# Standalone Django application with pyinstaller on Windows

Tags: django, windows, pyinstaller

I need to package a (rather simple) django application into a standalone executable on windows. After some failed attempts with py2exe (I really don't understand why everybody recommends it for django, it seems extremely complicated to set up) I tried `pyinstaller`. It does package the application without complaining, but if I try to run it using `myapp.exe runserver localhost:8000`, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_
module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "...\build\ck\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.test", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_
module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "...\build\ck\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.test.client", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_
module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "...\build\ck\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.db", line 11, in <module>
  File "...\build\ck\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.conf", line 52, in __getattr__
  File "...\build\ck\out00-PYZ.pyz\django.conf", line 45, in _setup
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must eith
er define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

My `manage.py` script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import Cookie
import django.test
import HTMLParser
from django.conf import settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Why does it not recognize the environment variable and how can I fix that?

Comment: Could you elaborate why `django.test.client` is being called in your application?

Comment: Hi, importing django.test apparently helps with some imports that pyinstaller would not find otherwise. The issue here ist, of course, that django.test must be importet _after_ I set the configuration file.

Comment: Exactly. Glad that it works for you now :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by importing django.test *after* the line

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
```